When SG-1 arrives in 1969, why is it initially an "empty" gate room?
In the episode "1969", SG-1 accidentally travels back in time to 1969. They emerge in what initially appears to be an unoccupied gate room, which transforms around them to its "actual" 1969 configuration as a missile silo. How can this be explained in-universe?
Based on series canon up to this point, the gate was unearthed in Giza in 1928, experimented on in some unspecified lab in 1945, and presumably kept in storage (as is later established in the episode), until off-screen events leading up to the 1994 movie. Given this, shouldn't they have emerged in the storage facility?
In time travel stories, we may see time travelers arriving in an environment only to see it transform around them, but that is usually because they are "returning" to time from a past they have just altered, or as in the original "Back to the Future", Marty's family snapshot from the "future" transforms due to his impact on the past. SG-1 arrival in 1969 does not fit this scenario.
Is there any consistent explanation for this, or is it forever a hand-waved plot inconsistency?

"I'm fairly certain that we've traveled back in time, roughly about thirty years. For a second or two, I think we were in both time-frames simultaneously, which is why the Stargate seemed to be there one minute and was gone the next." - Hand-waved

Out of universe I'd chalk this one up to early installment weirdness. This is the first time Stargate uses time travel and the rules just weren't figured out yet. Future versions of this mechanism require a gate on both ends.

I have been unable to locate an actual shooting script for this episode. There are plenty of transcripts, but no actual shooting script to be found. As such, this answer will, by necessity, contain only the information presented on-screen in dialog in two separate scenes. (With credit to Valorum for beating me to it in the comments.)
(they have just arrived and the gate room dissolves)

JACK: Captain Carter, where are we?
CARTER: I don't know, sir. For a minute there, we were back in the Gate
Room.

(and, later in the episode)

CARTER: I'm fairly certain that we've traveled back in time, roughly about thirty years. For a second or two, I think we were in
both time-frames simultaneously, which is why the Stargate seemed to
be there one minute and was gone the next.
JACK: Little bump in the calculations, Captain?
CARTER: I'm sorry, sir. I don't know what to say.

The events of this episode are only referenced in detail again in a humorous manner in the episode "200" in a joke at Mitchell's expense; otherwise, all other references in both SG-1 and Atlantis amounted to "SG-1 once traveled through time/that's how we know time travel is possible." This specific method of time travel was also a plot point in the Stargate: Continuum movie, although no mention was made of the "Gate Room" oddity.
No further explanation was provided.

This method of time travel was also used in the episode 2010, which also had no indication of the "Gate Room" oddity. I don't think there's ever any in-universe explanation of why the same time travel method had different results.

minnmass, thank you. :) I had a vague feeling that this had come up somewhere else besides Continuum, but I couldn't recall what it was before I posted my answer. I overlooked "2010" in my search because I was focused on all the later time-travel plots that centered around purpose-built Ancient tech.

The episode "1969" is unusual in time travel events of the SG-1 universe in one regard: wormhole has been redirected back to Earth due to both trajectory passing the solar flare, and too close to Sun's gravity well. Thus it has been slingshot back, since we know gravity can affect the subspace wormhole (in more than one way)...
Normally this would not be possible - both minimum distance requirement and "dialling own number" are violated here - but since SGC does not operate gate with DHD, the exceptions seem to apply.
The way gate operates is that it creates a one-way subspace wormhole, which exists outside the time-space continuum. It can even be argued that the wormhole creates it's own mini-universe (as amply demonstrated in SG-1: Continuum). This is also supported by the numerous instances of the time-travel wormhole, connecting the origin and destination for the duration of the wormhole existence (in other words: you need to establish the wormhole at specific time and route to get the desired outcome, but you do not need to enter the wormhole at specific time). However, it is also contradicted in 1969, too, by Cassandra:

 You entered the Stargate a few seconds too soon, so the flare threw >! you far into the future. I've come to send you back where you belong.

So you have to make up your own mind on exact physics of the wormhole in that specific regard.
But there's more: because SGC is operating stargate  with equivalent of duct tape and baling wire, all kinds of safeguards and/or limitations, normally "hard-coded" in DHD are not in place, making possible all kinds of weird-a*s s**t to happen. Collapse a star here, time travel there, create black hole over there... Creating a wormhole looping back onto the same stargate, but 30 years earlier does not look as impressive as those, really.
That being said, the questions the episode is raising, like "why it didn't connect to the actual 1969 stargate in it's physical location?" and so on, are all valid points.
To address that, here's my explanation of the events of 1969:

Outgoing wormhole passed through CME (solar flare),
It also passed too close to the Sun's gravity well:


(Carter):
"This time of year, the direct line between P2X-555 and the Earth
takes us within 70,000 miles of the sun. I have to update the
computer's drift calculation to include gravitational space/time
warping."


Causing it to slingshot back to Earth, and probably some other phenomena affecting physics of the wormhole:


(Carter)
If the wormhole itself was redirected closer to the sun because of the
Earth's magnetic field, (drawing a circle in the dirt)
the increased gravity could slingshot us back to Earth.
4. Because it also passed through CME, it now targets the 1969 time frame:
(Carter)
That's the only explanation. We had to have been sent back because of a solar flare.

(...)

What if a massive solar flare just happened to occur at the exact
moment that we were traveling between Earth and another Stargate?


Thus allowing the gate to connect to itself, because of the multiple safeguards not present in the dialing computer's software,
In effect creating a "closed loop" wormhole, where SG-1 is exiting that wormhole in the same gate room they left from.
and the disappearance of the gate in next few moments is the collapse of that mini-universe the wormhole created.

This exact mechanism has also been used in SG-1 episode 2010:

A number of years ago a freak accident sent us back to 1969. We know
that by dialling coordinates that are precisely on the opposite sides
of the sun at the exact moment of a solar flare, it causes the
wormhole to turn back towards Earth on itself and it creates a time
distortion. Now, theoretically, we could send ourselves a message.

So, to bottom-line it all: it's because of extreme gravity.

I think the issue OP is talking about is less them connecting to their own gate in the past, and more them emerging in a different location than the gate is. So the wormhole isn't terminating at the gate in the past, but in an empty space.

No, the wormhole is most definitely NOT terminating in an empty space. That's the whole point of my answer - it terminates at the originating stargate, but 30 years earlier and it has to do with the wormhole being outside time-space continuum.Or, to be more precise, it creates its own time-space continuum and the terminating stargate existed in 1969 time frame for the duration of the wormhole.We know that extreme gravity alters the physics of the wormhole, so it's entirely possible that numerous rules were broken at that time.

This answer got a major upgrade overnight, and I appreciate the effort and use of quotes. But, in my opinion, the problem still stands: we have no known out-of-universe word-of-God explanation from the writer/producers/etc. about why this happened, and neither do we have any direct in-universe explanation (besides Carter's hand-wave that I quoted) from the episode itself. SG1 arrived in a place where the Stargate was not actually present, and we are left with no explanation why that was the case. All future time travel via this exact solar flare method did not display this behavior.

@TheMaskedBowler That is not correct: This is a very unique situation, but not an only one. The 2010 episode uses same exactly mechanism. "A number of years ago a freak accident sent us back to 1969. We know that by dialling coordinates that are precisely on the opposite sides of the sun at the exact moment of a solar flare, it causes the wormhole to turn back towards Earth on itself and it creates a time distortion. Now, theoretically, we could send ourselves a message."
